# After installing MariaDB, mysql_secure_installation produces error, cannot connect mysqld.sock

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mariadb

After installing MariaDB, mysql_secure_installation produces the error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

A review of `/var/run/myssqld` shows that there is no `mysqld.sock` file:

```
find / mysqld.sock produces
find: ‘mysqld.sock’: No such file or directory
```

Issuing a command `sudo service mysql start` produces:

> jmysql ob for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
> See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Issung `mysql --version` produces:

```
mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.25-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

This appears to be a very common problem. I have reviewed 20(?) similar questions, and tried the solutions suggested.

OS - Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: take a look into the mariadb errorlog, there you find the cause and some hints how to handle it, also you can check iif it starts at all

Comment: `journalctl -n 40 -u mariadb.service`. Edit question to include information if you have trouble diagnosing. Use `systemctl start mariadb.service` to start the service.

Comment: The .sock file may be in the datadir which by default is `/var/lib/mysql/`. You can tell the client to use a particular socket file with a command such as `mysql --socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`. Failing that, you may be able to connect over TCP, although there probably isn't a root user for this, so probably won't work on a fresh installation: `mysql -u root --protocol tcp`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqld - cannot connect to socket after changing datadir location](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/mysqld-cannot-connect-to-socket-after-changing-datadir-location)